# How do I get the lua libraries for linux so that I can use them in C?

Tags: c, lua

I am following this tutorial https://lucasklassmann.com/blog/2019-02-02-how-to-embeddeding-lua-in-c/#installation and I was wondering how I could get the following libraries installed on ubuntu:

```c
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
```

I tried installing all sorts of lua-related things, like:

```bash
sudo apt-get install liblua5.1-0-dev
sudo apt-get install lua-devel
```

But I still could not get things to work. Does anyone know how to get lua working for C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ubuntu packages for Lua add an extra subdirectory so that you can have multiple versions installed at once. Either do this instead:

```c
#include <lua5.1/lua.h>
#include <lua5.1/lualib.h>
#include <lua5.1/lauxlib.h>
```

Or pass `-I/usr/include/lua5.1` on the compiler command line. (If you get undefined references errors after either of these options, then you probably need to append `-llua5.1` to the compiler command line.)

Comment: And the `pkgconf` or `pkg-config` commands can be used to get the required options. E.g. `pkg-config --cflags lua` and `pkg-config --libs lua` to get the CFLAGS and LIBS options for the default liblua version. To get the options for a specific version of liblua, replace `lua` in the `pkg-config` command with `lua5.1` (or `lua51`) for example.